# PdfBox 2.0.20 adding signature field to signed document and setting NeedAppearances to true brokes existing signature

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

1. I have a document with one signatrue field which is signed - all ok.
2. I add another signature field to the document, set `NeedAppearances` to `false`, and call `saveIncremental`.
3. The document is now broken, Adobe Reader informs me that document was modified after it was signed.

When I add signature field **without setting `NeedAppearances`**, then everything's allright.

Can anyone tell me, if this is a bug in PdfBox or I am doing somenthing wrong?

Comment: Isn't `false` the default value of `NeedAppearances`. This flag doesn't make sense in combination with a digitial signature because it means that the reader should re-create the appearances of form fields at opeing time. For sure this re-creation will end in a modified document. IIRC Adobe Reader e.g. doesn't show the signature panel at all if this flag is set.

Comment: Could you share both the original, single-signature file and the double-signature one for analysis?

Comment: Don't touch `NeedAppearances`, this means trouble: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3738

Comment: Thx @TilmanHausherr, this means I need to learn more about this flag.

Comment: Thx @JanSlabon, now I see the sense of that.